# What does it mean if the fundamental group is Abelian?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

On proving the problem that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is Abelian iff for every pair $\alpha$ and $\beta$ if paths form $x_0$to$x_1$, we have $\hat \alpha=\hat\beta$ where $X$ is path-connected space
,

I'm curious of meaning for what fundamental group is Abelian. If possible, could you explain the case of product of given two distinct loop would not be commutable on the $R^2$?.

Comment: "the case of product of given two distinct loop would not be commutable on the $R^2$?" I can't imderstand what this means.

Comment: I mean if $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is not Abelian, we can find some distinct loops $f$ and $g$ such that there doesn't exist path homotopy between $f*g$ and $g*f$. So I want to ask you to show this kind of loops in $R^2$.

Comment: For an example just cut out a couple of holes in the plane and go around these.

Comment: But $\Bbb R^2$ (if that's what you mean) _does_ have abelian fundamental group (in fact, it is trivial).

Comment: aha. your right, it must be trivial but, what I expected to see is there exist such fundamental group based on imaginable space such as $R^2$. So, our space could be considered $R_2$ with some hole.

Comment: check out https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1644622/4280 e.g. or [this presentation](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/jordan/gt1112-s5.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for link, I'll check out!

Comment: A figure 8 in the plane, then going around loop1 once then loop 2 once, or the other way around (starting and ending in the middle) is the classical example of non-commuting loops.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the wedge sum of two circles (that is, two circles that are connected by one point, let's call it the base point). By Van Kampen's theorem, you can see that the fundamental group of this space is the free product $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$.

Obviously this is not abelian. In fact, if you consider the loop $\alpha$ which does one turn of the first circle, from the base point, and the loop $\beta$ which does one turn on the second cicrle from the base point, the images of these two loops in the fundamental group are not commuting.

Comment: ha. Thank for helping me. But, I don't learn about the Van Kampen's theorem yet. I want to ask that the reason why the two loops you offer in the fundamental group are not commuting is based on the theorem?

Comment: @fivestar You'll have to learn it, or you won't be able to compute real fundamental groups. Get Hatcher and learn!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma aha, thank you for informing me this fact... . I'll have to study more to deal with this theorem, because it is further topic in my book by munkres.

Comment: @fivestar Munkres also covers it well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, right. then, it remains only for me to study hard !

Comment: @fivestar sure. Fundamental groups are much easier to define than to compute; you need more theory to do interesting examples.

Answer (score 1):

A non-Abelian fundamental group $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ means that there are two loops $\alpha, \beta: [0,1] \to X$, so continuous with $\alpha(0) = \alpha(1) =\beta(0) = \beta(1) = x_0$, such that there is no ($x_0$-fixing) homotopy between $\alpha \cdot \beta$ and $\beta \cdot \alpha$, where $\alpha \cdot \beta$ is (the homotopy class of) the map that sends $t$ to $\alpha(2t)$ for $0 \le t \le \frac12$ and to $\beta(2t-1)$ for $\frac12 \le t \le 1$, as usual, and $\beta \cdot \alpha$ is the similarly glued map in the other order. 
This just follows from the definitions.

Comment: I understand in the meaning of the definition. But. I want to see example of such case with reason why such loops couldn't find homotopy.